# Read Laravel cookie outside app

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

At the moment I have a folder with Laravel's app (login and registration) and another folder with the rest of the website (outside Laravel and written in core PHP)

Since sessions in Laravel cannot be shared with core PHP I would like to store username's details (after login or registration) on a cookie and then read it outside Laravel's app. So far I tried adding my cookie to `EncryptCookies` so it wont be encrypted and then populating it with `setcookie("Test", 'dsadsadsa1234',15,"");` but when I try to echo it outside with core PHP with `echo $_COOKIE['Test'];` it's empty.

Is there any other way of sharing information between Laravel and plain PHP? I know having a cookie with sensitive information is not secure at all so I was thinking on encrypting it along with some other text so I can then decrypt it and verify if it was tampered or not but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: How you access the 'plain' php area? Does your laravel site sit at say 'http://website/site' and php 'plain' area sits at 'http://website/php'?

Comment: My laravel is at `website/login` and my php is at `website/`

Answer (score -1):

Within Laravel

```
setcookie("test", 'dsadsadsa1234',15,"/"); //<-- 4th parameter is a slash here
```

Within PHP

```
echo $_COOKIE['test']
```

That 4th parameter in Laravel setCookie() sets the variable at the project root

Comment: I keep getting `Undefined index: test` when doing `echo $_COOKIE['test']`

Comment: Can you put 0 as the 3rd parameter? Just testing a theory.

Comment: @EddyTheDove I don't know what theory you're talking about, but in Laravel context that 0 saved my life. Thanks